# Kinect laser scan angle

Tags: kinect, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you set the min and max laser scan angle for the kinect?  I have checked out dynamic reconfigure and do not see any way of changing the angles.  In ros electric, the view angle was almost 180 degrees, in groovy it seems to be only about 57 degrees.  I need to have the same view angle that groovy did.  How can I change the min and max view angle?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67025/kinect-laser-scan-angle/) by [mickey11592](https://answers.ros.org/users/5154/mickey11592/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect has a field of view of 57º, I do not know any mean to change that other than using an optical adapter. You can see the specs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131033.aspx).

A field of view of 180º for a Kinect seems like a bug...

If 57º is too narrow, the obvious solution if you can afford it would be to use one or more additional devices.

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mickey11592](https://answers.ros.org/users/5154/mickey11592/) on 2013-07-10**:
Thank you for your reply. I do not think that 180 degrees was a bug though because my whole class used the turtlebot with kinect running ros electric for a few projects and we all received approximately 180 degrees as a viewing angle.  I am hoping there is a way to receive that again in groovy.

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-10**:
As po1 said, there's no way for the kinect to physically see more than about 57 degrees.  You can pad this on both sides with "don't know" readings to get 180 degrees of scan, but there isn't a way to fill these additional 133 degrees with meaningful readings.

**Comment by [mickey11592](https://answers.ros.org/users/5154/mickey11592/) on 2013-07-11**:
I don't understand how the kinect had approximately 180 degree field of view when running ros electric then.  They were not padded readings, they were accurate since we used them to drive forward and stay in the center of the hallway, and used rviz to view and test the scans.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-18**:
Micket11592, how did you implement the code for the turtlebot so that it stays in the middle of the hallway? could you share your code please?